# Error while loading dataframe to snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While loading data from python dataframe to snowflake I am getting below error. Can someone please explain these errors in details?

> Python data type [method] cannot be automatically mapped to Snowflake data type. Specify the snowflake data type explicitly.

Below is the code I am using to load data into snowflake:

```py
df.to_sql(table, engine, index=False, method='multi',chunksize=3000)
```

Comment: Can you use dtype to specify the data type explicitly, as per the error message?  Or does that not work in your example?

Comment: Since I am loading python dataframe with more than 30 columns...I am not sure how to and where to specify the dtypes...please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the Snowflake [Connector for Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#using-pandas-dataframes-with-the-python-connector) with pandas to read and write data to Snowflake. Assuming you have this set up correctly, then when calling `to_sql` you need to use `method=pd_writer`, [as per the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-pd-writer).

You are currently using `method=multi` which is probably why you are receiving the above error.

Comment: I have used pd_writer method as well but got below error: Failed processing pyformat-parameters : Binding data in type (method) is not supported

Comment: There must be something in your dataframe that is not a supported data type for snowflake. Looks like there might be a method in one of your columns.

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code for this to be debugged further. There's not enough information here to understand what you're doing.