# How to save polars dataframes to snowflake without loosing dtype information?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe that I'm trying to persist to snowflake.

I have no issues saving and loading the table from parquet, but when I do:

```py
df.write_database(table_name='test_table', if_table_exists='replace', connection=con_str, engine='adbc')

df_new = pl.read_database_uri('SELECT * FROM test_table', uri=con_str, engine='adbc')
```

The data types of columns are not preserved.

For example:

```
shape: (3, 10)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────────────┬───────────┬───┬───────────┬──────────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ A1  ┆ A2  ┆ B1               ┆ B2        ┆ … ┆ As        ┆ Bs               ┆ D1    ┆ D2         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---              ┆ ---       ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[f64]        ┆ list[i64] ┆   ┆ struct[2] ┆ struct[2]        ┆ cat   ┆ cat        │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════════════╪═══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪══════════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ [2.2, 4.4, 6.6]  ┆ [1, 1]    ┆ … ┆ {1,2}     ┆ {[2.2, 4.4,      ┆ Hello ┆ The Test   │
│     ┆     ┆                  ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆ 6.6],[1, 1]}     ┆       ┆            │
│ 2   ┆ 8   ┆ [12.0, 16.0,     ┆ [1, 2]    ┆ … ┆ {2,8}     ┆ {[12.0, 16.0,    ┆ World ┆ Was For    │
│     ┆     ┆ 14.0]            ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆ 14.0],[1, 2]}    ┆       ┆            │
│ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ [152.0, 257.0,   ┆ [2, 1]    ┆ … ┆ {3,7}     ┆ {[152.0, 257.0,  ┆ !     ┆ The Takers │
│     ┆     ┆ 252.0]           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆ 252.0],[2, 1]}   ┆       ┆            │
└─────┴─────┴──────────────────┴───────────┴───┴───────────┴──────────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

becomes

```
shape: (3, 10)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┬──────┬───┬────────────┬───────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ A1  ┆ A2  ┆ B1     ┆ B2   ┆ … ┆ As         ┆ Bs        ┆ D1    ┆ D2         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ str    ┆ str  ┆   ┆ str        ┆ str       ┆ str   ┆ str        │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╪══════╪═══╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 2.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ [      ┆ [    ┆ … ┆ {          ┆ {         ┆ World ┆ Was For    │
│     ┆     ┆   12,  ┆   1, ┆   ┆   "A1": 2, ┆   "B1": [ ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   16,  ┆   2  ┆   ┆   "A2": 8  ┆     12,   ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   14   ┆ ]    ┆   ┆ }          ┆     16,   ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆ ]      ┆      ┆   ┆            ┆     …     ┆       ┆            │
│ 3.0 ┆ 7.0 ┆ [      ┆ [    ┆ … ┆ {          ┆ {         ┆ !     ┆ The Takers │
│     ┆     ┆   152, ┆   2, ┆   ┆   "A1": 3, ┆   "B1": [ ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   257, ┆   1  ┆   ┆   "A2": 7  ┆     152,  ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   252  ┆ ]    ┆   ┆ }          ┆     257,  ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆ ]      ┆      ┆   ┆            ┆   …       ┆       ┆            │
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ [      ┆ [    ┆ … ┆ {          ┆ {         ┆ Hello ┆ The Test   │
│     ┆     ┆   2.2, ┆   1, ┆   ┆   "A1": 1, ┆   "B1": [ ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   4.4, ┆   1  ┆   ┆   "A2": 2  ┆     2.2,  ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆   6.6  ┆ ]    ┆   ┆ }          ┆     4.4,  ┆       ┆            │
│     ┆     ┆ ]      ┆      ┆   ┆            ┆   …       ┆       ┆            │
└─────┴─────┴────────┴──────┴───┴────────────┴───────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Here is the python code to create a test df if you want to reproduce the issue:

```py
df_for_testing = pl.DataFrame({
    'A1': [1,2,3],
    'A2': [2,8,7],
    'B1':[[2.2,4.4,6.6],[12,16,14],[152,257,252]],
    'B2':[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]],
    'C1':['Hello', 'World','!'],
    'C2':['The Test', 'Was For', 'The Takers']
}).with_columns([
    pl.struct(['A1','A2']).alias('As'),
    pl.struct(['B1','B2']).alias('Bs'),
]).with_columns(
    D1 = pl.col('C1').cast(pl.Categorical), 
    D2 = pl.col('C2').cast(pl.Categorical)
)
```

You'll note specifically that `pl.List`, `pl.Struct`, `pl.Categorical` columns all became `pl.String` columns.

In snowflake the issue seems to be less serious:
[image]

Thought still some data type information is being lost.

Any ideas?

I tried connecting via the ADBC driver, and also specifying the schema when reading from the database, but no luck.

Also tried a `.to_pandas().to_sql(...)` but it has the same issue (and pandas itself does not support the polars data types)

I'm considering setting up snowpipe to read directly from parquet files in blob storage, but not worth doing if snowflake will mangle the data type information.

Note that these questions:

- [Polars DataFrame save to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320233/polars-dataframe-save-to-sql)
- [Error while loading dataframe to snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286234/error-while-loading-dataframe-to-snowflake)
- [How to read and write pandas/pyspark dataframe to Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449160/how-to-read-and-write-pandas-pyspark-dataframe-to-snowflake)

Do not address the issue. I can read/write data to snowflake, I just have the issue of data types.

## EDIT

So far I've written a helper function to try and cast the table returned by the ADBC connector to the correct data types as stored in the schema of the outbound dataframe.

```py
def match_to_outbound_schema(df:pl.DataFrame, outbound_schema:dict, verbose:bool=False)->pl.DataFrame:
    
    assert df.schema.keys() == outbound_schema.keys()
    
    current_to_outbound = {
        column: (current, target) for column, current, target in zip(df.columns, df.schema.values(), outbound_schema.values())
    }
    
    for column, (current, target) in current_to_outbound.items():
        
        if current == target:
            if verbose: print(f'Nothing to do for {column}')
            
        if current.is_numeric() and target.is_numeric():
            if verbose: print(f'Numeric casting from {current} to {target} for {column}')
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(column).cast(target))
            
        if current.is_(pl.String()) and target.is_nested():
            if verbose: print(f'Parsing from {current} to {target} for {column}')
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(column).str.json_decode().cast(target))
            
        if current.is_temporal() and target.is_temporal():
            if verbose: print(f'Temporal casting from {current} to {target} for {column}')
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(column).cast(target))
            
        if current.is_(pl.String()) and target.is_(pl.Categorical()): # <--- This breaks if one does not instantiate the dtype
            if verbose: print(f'Encoding from {current} to {target} for {column}')
            df = df.with_columns(pl.col(column).cast(target))
            
    current_to_outbound_after_casting = {
        column: (current, target) for column, current, target in zip(df.columns, df.schema.values(), outbound_schema.values())
    }
    
    matching = {column: current.is_(target) for column, (current, target) in current_to_outbound_after_casting.items()}
    
    errors = [
        f'> Column {column} is {current} but should be {target}' for column, (current, target) in current_to_outbound_after_casting.items() if not current.is_(target)
    ]
    
    assert all(matching.values()), 'The following columns have bad data types: \n' + '\n'.join(errors)
    
    # one final check:
    df = df.cast(outbound_schema)
    
    return df
    

df_from_snowflake.pipe(match_to_outbound_schema, df_for_testing.schema, verbose=True)
```

Comment: [It doesn't look good](https://arrow.apache.org/adbc/0.5.1/driver/snowflake.html#type-support). Looks like you'll have to do [str.json_decode](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.json_decode.html)

Comment: That's great to know - I'll work on an util function to parse the table returned by snowflake. Do you know any Arrow compatible warehouses while we are at it?

Comment: I just store parquets in Azure Blob storage and if it's a "big" query I'll use Azure Synapse but I don't think I ever store nested types but if I did, they have the same issue. Google's Big Query might send data in ipc format which should support nested types but I've never used it so that's just something I think I remember reading somewhere so I don't really know.

Comment: Noted. I have been using blob storage too, but I'm hitting the limits of what predicate pushdown can achieve in terms of latency/memory. I want to offer fast reads over the parquet files, but ever finer row-groups have a limit. Storing the parquets/dataframes in snowflake was one approach, the other being a REST api that keeps the dataframes in memory and returns the selected rows. But at that point I'm rolling my own read-only db, which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: If you want low latency then Azure Synapse is definitely not the answer, not that I recommended it. Azure Cosmos nosql serverless has fast responses but all the data is going to be returned as json and it doesn't do much more than filters but if your use case is just random access to data then it could be a good fit.